# Removing only Highlighting in word 2013 from pasted code segment

Tags: ms-word, notepad++

I am using notepad++ for coding and I am coping my coding to MS word 2013 by plugins->NppExport ->copy html to clip board. when I paste the code it looks like below.
[image]

I just want to remove only highlighting from the above not any other formatting.what should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Settings. Go to **`Settings -> Style Configurator then Select theme: Default(stylers.xml)`**

Or it could be your Language: Style **`Background Color`**

See below Image

[image]